# Analyze a IPIP Survey with semantic differential and a spider web modal

Tags: ipip

I conducted an IPIP survey with 20 groups of 100 participants.
Now I have to analyze the survey.

The website https://ipip.ori.org/newScoringInstructions.htm says:

> Once numbers are assigned for all of the items in the scale, just sum all the values to obtain a total scale score.

Instead, I calculated an average value for each question.
I think I can compare the results of the groups better this way.
Is the evaluation still valid?

I have represented the result as semantic differential and a spider web modal.
[image: semantic differential]